# How do I make an OnClick function that will change a word when a user clicks it to another word?

Tags: javascript, html, function, replace, onclick

Okay so, I want to make an `OnClick` function in JavaScript that makes it so when a user clicks on it, it will change the word. Is there a `replaceword()` function or something that which will let me do so? I know this is not real code, but for example:

```
<p>Quickly <span onclick="replaceword('Surf');">Search</span> The Web!</p>
```

If there is, then can someone tell me also how to reverse the code maybe? So when they click on it the second time, it will change back to "Search"?

Comment: No, HTML does not have functions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user made no attempt to solve the problem himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any native function, but you can create on your own.

```
function replaceword(that, word, oword) {
    that.textContent = that.textContent == oword ? word : oword;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
<p>Quickly<span onclick="replaceword(this,'Surf','Search');">Search</span>The Web!</p>
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t6bvA/6

Comment: I'm new to having an account on here, heh... So how do I do that?

Comment: This doesn't return the original value when clicked a second time.

Comment: This would only work for two clicks; what happens when `clicked` is equal to 3, or 4, or 5? Also, be mindful when using [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerText).

Comment: @AmitJoki Still a bit inefficient; since every other click you'll be setting the value twice. Once to the initial value, and then immediately overwriting it to the new value. You also now have a variable floating out of context.

Comment: @JonathanSampson What to you mean by "variable floating out of context"?

Comment: @AmitJoki Looking much better :) You could also remove the `this` and `that` parameters, as `this` will implicitly point to the element clicked.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, unfortunately not working. I tried that before http://jsfiddle.net/t6bvA/7/

Comment: @AmitJoki Ah, you're right. I was thinking the inline `onclick` method implicitly passed the element as its context, much like `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to jump between multiple words, you'll need to store them someplace. You could have two words in the sentence, and toggle the visibility of one or the other (which doesn't scale well), or you could even store them as values on an attribute placed on the element itself.

```html
<p>Hello, <span data-values="World,People,Stack Overflow">World</span>.</p>
```

I have placed all possible values within the `data-values` attribute. Each distinct value is separated from the other values by a comma. We'll use this for creating an array of values next:

```js
// Leverage event-delegation via bubbling
document.addEventListener( "click", function toggleWords ( event ) {
    // A few variables to help us track important values/references
    var target = event.target, values = [], placed;
    // If the clicked element has multiple values
    if ( target.hasAttribute( "data-values" ) ) {
        // Split those values out into an array
        values = target.getAttribute( "data-values" ).split( "," );
        // Find the location of its current value in the array
        // IE9+ (Older versions supported by polyfill: http://goo.gl/uZslmo)
        placed = values.indexOf( target.textContent );
        // Set its text to be the next value in the array
        target.textContent = values[ ++placed % values.length ];   
    }
});
```

The results:

[image]

The above listens for clicks on the `document`. There are numerous reasons why this is a good option:

- You don't need to wait for the document to finish loading to run this code
- This code will work for any elements added asynchronously later in the page life
- Rather than setting up one handler for each element, we have one handler for all.

There are some caveats; you may run into a case where the click is prevented from propagating up past a particular parent element. In that case, you would want to add the eventListener closer to your target region, so the likeliness that bubbling will be prevented is less.

There are other benefits to this code as well:

- Logic is separated from markup
- Scale to any number of values without adjusting your JavaScript

A demo is available for your review online: http://jsfiddle.net/7N5K5/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p id="abc">Hello</p>
    <input type="submit" name="Change" onclick="change()">



function change(){
var ab=document.getElementById('abc').value;
ab.innerHTML="Hi, Bye";
}
```

I think so this should help you, you should go to site such as w3schools.com, its basic and it will answer your doubt

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you wanna use jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/R3Ume/2/

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Hello <a id='name'>John<a></p>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="replace" onclick="onClick();" />

<script>
function onClick() {    
    $('#name').text('world');
}
</script>
```